# qiwi api (python)

Tags: api, qiwi

Хотел реализовать управление кошельком киви через свой скрипт, но апи у меня отказывается работать. 
[image: Вот так пытаюсь авторизоваться, но выходит ошибка]
Ссылка на документация - https://developer.qiwi.com/qiwiwallet/qiwicom_ru.html
Что не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ найден (помог саппорт киви). Вот реализация получения tgt ticket'a

```
import getpass
import requests
import json

# номер кошелька в формате +79992223344
mylogin = '+7…'

# пароль от кошелька
mypassword = getpass.getpass('Password:')

def get_tgt_ticket(my_login,my_password):
    s = requests.Session()
    header = {'content-type': 'application/json',
          'X-Requested-With':'XMLHttpRequest',
          'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36'
         }
    s.headers=header
    r = s.post('https://auth.qiwi.com/cas/tgts', json = {'login':mylogin,'password':mypassword})
    tgt_Ticket = json.loads(r.text)['entity']['ticket']
    return tgt_Ticket

tgtTicket = get_tgt_ticket(mylogin,mypassword)
```

Comment: Отлично работает! Спасибо!